# Xamarin.iOS. UILabel is not shown

Tags: xamarin.ios, uilabel

My code:

```
public class AdViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    public void RecycleCell()
    {
         var _nativeAd = new NativeAdView();
         ContentView.AddSubview(_nativeAd.CreateNativeAd());
    }
}

public class NativeAdView
{
    public UIView CreateNativeAd()
    {
        var t1label = new UILabel();            
        t1label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(25);
        t1label.Text = "Test";
        t1label.TextColor = UIColor.White;

        return t1label;
    }
}
```

It using in RecycleCollectionView.

Text is not shown:

[image]

Why is the text not displayed? Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

> A view's frame (CGRect) is the position of its rectangle in the
>   superview's coordinate system. By default it starts at the top left.

If you don't specify a view's `frame` or `layout`, a view will not show in its `superview`.

**Solution:**

In your case, a `Frame` is need to add to the label to make sure the position of the label in your `RecycleCollectionView`.

For example:

```
 public class NativeAdView
            {
                public UIView CreateNativeAd()
                {
                    var t1label = new UILabel();
                    t1label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(25);
                    t1label.Text = "Test";
                    t1label.TextColor = UIColor.White;

                    t1label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
                    // you can define your Frame here
                    t1label.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(50,60,100,50);

                    return t1label;
                }
            }
```

You can also use `autolayout` to layout your view.

Refer : [autoLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout)